# ssl erros sending mail using devise in rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-6

I am deploying rails 6 in production. I am testing the mail function of devise and I am getting this error

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (hostname "localhost" does not match the server certificate):
```

how can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem**

If you encounter this problem when running Ruby on Rails:

OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (hostname "localhost" does not match the server certificate)
it is likely due to ActionMailer using the smtp as the delivery_method and your local mail server supporting TLS/SSL, but not having a correct/valid certificate.

**The solution**

You can add a valid certificate, but if the server is just used for sending out mails, this may not be suited. In that case, you can change the delivery_method to sendmail, which makes ActionMailer use the sendmail binary directly.

[source](https://www.nico.schottelius.org/blog/ruby-on-rails-fix-hostname-does-not-match-the-server-certificate/)